# Is it possible to add all (or a specific category's all products) woo-commerce product in a cart at once?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have few categories and few products in each category. I just wondering if there is any option to adding all products in a cart with a **single click**.

If adding all products is not possible then any one can help me if i can add a specific category with its all products.

NB: I know with Learning plugin like **Sensi** it can be possible but i dont want to use sensi.

Comment: You can create a function that uses woocommerces add_to_cart()

Comment: basically WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );